# Oracle Apex selected list, da updates "all" entries

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to update one line of the result (example at the end).

To do this i created an select list item (:P1_WIRKUNG (ID1)) and a textarea item (:P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG (DESCRIPTION)) to update an entry of database (ID1, ID2 (:P1_SEL_PFLANZE_ID), DESCRIPTION).

So when I want to update an entry, I can select a value from the select list item and fill the :P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG textarea. But when I do that, the DESCRIPTION of other entries is deleted and i dont know why... I dont get it...

DA:

```
BEGIN
   IF :P1_WIRKUNG IS NOT NULL AND :P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE TBL_PFLANZE_CON_WIRKUNG
          SET DESCRIPTION = :P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG
      WHERE ID2 = to_number(:P1_SEL_PFLANZE_ID) AND ID1 = to_number(:P1_WIRKUNG);
   END IF;
END;
```

before update:

| ID1 | ID2 | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 5678 | Description XYZ |
| 76 | 5678 |  |
| 96 | 5678 |  |

e.g. after update:

| ID1 | ID2 | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 5678 |  |
| 76 | 5678 | Description XYZ |
| 96 | 5678 |  |

EDIT:
to get the DESCRIPTION of selected item i use a change event (da) and set value via select statement (sql query)

Comment: Did you submit all items involved?

Comment: yes: first da: P1_WIRKUNG,P1_SEL_PFLANZE_ID,P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG
||| da in the "edit:" P1_WIRKUNG,P1_SEL_PFLANZE_ID (to fill the P1_WIRKUNG_BESCHREIBUNG)

Comment: This is not enough information to diagnose your issue. Would you be able to reproduce this in a test workspace on apex.oracle.com and give us access ?

Comment: This was a good hint... SRY... I recreated it on apex.oracle.com and there it works as expected...

Comment: Awesome that you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

A mistake on my part... I recreated it on apex.oracle.com and there it works as expected... Error is certainly in another DA or so... I will check this again ...